# know what are new users added on a Firebase list, even after a restart

Tags: node.js, firebase, user-accounts

As quoted in the documentation, I save users in a list. Users can log with both password and Facebook providers. (other providers may come later)

Then, I have a nodejs app that listens the user list and send me an email in case of new items.

This is easy with firebase, just add a child_added event listener. But as my app may restart for update/crash or any other reason, I do not want to get a email with every user at each time I restart the app. So I just save the latest userId that has been used to send an email.

```
var retrieveLatestAccountNotified = function () {
    ref.child("server-state").child("email-account").once("value", function (snapshot) {
        user = snapshot.val();
        console.log("Latest User Id : " + user);
        fetchUser(user);
        //fakeUser("");
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
};


var fetchUser = function (latestUserId) {
    ref.child("users").orderByKey().startAt(latestUserId).on("child_added", function (snapshot, prevChildKey) {
        if (snapshot.key() !== latestUserId) {
            var newUser = snapshot.val();
            console.log(newUser);
            sendEmail.newAccountEmail(ses, newUser, snapshot.key(), function (err, data) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                console.log('Email sent:');
                console.log(data);
                ref.child("server-state").child("email-account").set(snapshot.key());
            });
        }

    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
};
```

The problem is that FB generates different userId type depending on the selected provider, so my mechanism will not work.

How to deal with that ?

- Add priority when the user is created
  => as many clients may add users, this mechanism has to be used in each client implementation
- Add a child (creation_date) in every user
  => adding extra info in user
- Add another list that saves which users have been notified 
  => require to loop on both full list

Any educated proposition is welcome !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common approach used for this is close to your #3:

> Add another list that saves which users have been notified => require to loop on both full list

Typically you'd add a queue for sending the email notifications. This queue is purely for sending the notifications, so the server removes the item from it once it's done.

In its simplest form:

```
ref.child('emailNotificationQueue').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  sendEmailToAnthony(snapshot.val(), function() {
    snapshot.ref().remove();
  });
});
```

For better scalability and many other reasons, you might want to use [firebase-queue](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-15-introducing-firebase-queue.html). But it is a (beautifully) souped up version of such a loop.

You can take two approaches to the queue:

1. Your app writes the new user to `/users` and the notification to `/emailNotificationQueue`. This usually works, but has some nasty race/error conditions if a malicious client (or coding mistakes) writes one and not the other). While you can safeguard against these, there sometimes is a simpler approach.
2. Your app writes the new users to `/newUserQueue`. The server reads them from there, sends the email *and* adds them to `/users`.

Comment: I did know about firebase-queue, it seems powerful. Would you recommend making separate queue for every topic, of adding a specId in task?

Comment: That really depends on how you prefer to structure your back-end code and whether the tasks are sufficiently different. You could even have the initial "createUser" be a task, that then fans out other "subtasks". But I usually prefer a simpler system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store time stamp when the email was last sent in user object itself, and query by child with time stamp property. This approach has one problem where the very first time it might resend mails for all users.

```
var fetchUser = function (last_email_sent_ts) {
  // as email_sent_ts will only have valid value when email is sent
  // if we query by email_sent_ts equals to null shall return all the
  // values that are missed during the restart
   ref.child("users")
      .orderByChild("email_sent_ts")
      .equalTo(null)
      .on("child_added", success , error);       

    function success(snapshot, prevChildKey) {            
       var newUser = snapshot.val();

       if (newUser.email_sent_ts === last_email_sent_ts) return;

       sendEmail.newAccountEmail(ses, newUser, snapshot.key(), emailCallback);

        function emailCallback(err, data) {
             if (err) throw err;

             var email_sent_ts = new Date().getTime();

             ref.child("users")
                .child(snapshot.key())
                .child('email_sent_ts').set(email_sent_ts);

         }                                       
     }
}
```